# ACF not showing below products

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I can't seem to work out why my ACF fields will not display below my woo-commerce products on the featured page when they display fine above them?

**Products**

```
<div id="post-load" class="row products">
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'nopaging' => true,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => 'featured',
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
        ),
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product; ?>

        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

**ACF Example** (This works fine if placed above the products)

```
<?php
$features = get_field('features');
if( $features ): ?>                 
<div class="col-md-12"><h3 class="txtc"><?php echo esc_html( $features['title'] ); ?></h3></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where and how are you pasting the given code? inside template-part/content-product.php? or?